# How to set HDMI Port 1 to be used by default on Pi4?

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display

During some experiments it looks like my HDMI port 0 broke down. I still can SSH to it.

```
tvservice -M <display on port 0>
```

Does not show any activity on port 0 when I plug the HDMI cable in and out. However doing this with HDMI port 1 clearly shows that attach and detach the cable.

However, on port one nothing is displayed. How do I tell my pi to solely use HDMI port 1?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the line

```
framebuffer_priority=7
```

to `/boot/config.txt` .